# Domain without WWW not working

Tags: domain, web, hosting

My domain is not resolving without using the `www.` subdomain.

I can't work out why... here is my current zone file:

```
rcnhca.org.uk 86400 SOA ns0.gradwell.com hostmaster.gradwell.com 2012 10800 3600 604800 86400
*.rcnhca.org.uk.    86400   IN  A   195.74.61.93
*.rcnhca.org.uk.    86400   IN  MX  10 mail-in-1.lb.gradwell.net.
rcnhca.org.uk.  86400   IN  A   195.74.61.93
rcnhca.org.uk.  86400   IN  MX  10 mail-in-2.lb.gradwell.net.
rcnhca.org.uk.  86400   IN  MX  10 mail-in-1.lb.gradwell.net.
rcnhca.org.uk.  86400   IN  NS  ns2.gradwell.net.
rcnhca.org.uk.  86400   IN  NS  ns1.gradwell.net.
rcnhca.org.uk.  86400   IN  NS  ns0.gradwell.com.
autoreply.rcnhca.org.uk.    86400   IN  A   79.135.125.10
autoreply.rcnhca.org.uk.    86400   IN  MX  10 mail-in-1.lb.gradwell.net.
list.rcnhca.org.uk. 60  IN  A   212.11.71.211
list.rcnhca.org.uk. 86400   IN  MX  10 list.rcnhca.org.uk.
list.rcnhca.org.uk. 86400   IN  MX  20 mxbackup.gradwell.net.
lists.rcnhca.org.uk.    86400   IN  A   193.111.200.31
lists.rcnhca.org.uk.    86400   IN  MX  10 lists.rcnhca.org.uk.
localhost.rcnhca.org.uk.    86400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
pop3.rcnhca.org.uk. 86400   IN  A   79.135.125.10
pop3.rcnhca.org.uk. 86400   IN  MX  10 mail-in-1.lb.gradwell.net.
post.rcnhca.org.uk. 86400   IN  A   79.135.125.10
smtp.rcnhca.org.uk. 86400   IN  CNAME   relay.gradwell.com.
```

Can anyone spot why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DNS is fine and both rcnhca.org.uk and wwww.rcnhca.org.uk resolve to 195.74.61.93. The issue is the configuration of the VirtualHosts. Follow the instructions here:

http://www.gradwell.com/support/kb/article.php?id=165#stepone

Or speak to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

Your domain resolves just fine, but your web server is configured to need the www part. You have to configure it so that it reacts to both rcnhca.org.uk and www.rcnhca.org.uk.

How this is done is dependent on your OS and web server, which you don't state.

Answer (score 0):

DNS seems to be fine. Opening a browser gives "No Virtual Host Configured", which leads me to believe you need to configure your web site with whatever the Linux/Unix equivalent of host headers is.